# Collapsible Sidebar Without Visible Reflow on Content Inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a 3 column layout where I want the left and right columns to be collapsible. I want the following:

1. A smooth slide
2. Sidebars that have a percentage width
3. No visible reflow on the sidebar content
4. No `white-space: nowrap;`, as this will mess with the display of the sidebar content.
5. Allow for complex content inside the sidebar, not just simple text in a `<p>` tag as in the codepen example below.
6. No hardcoded pixel widths - I know you can add a width on an inner div together with `overflow:hidden` on the parent, but I don't want to hardcode a large width.
7. I need the sidebar widths to be relative to the immediate parent (and not the viewport), in case the 3-column layout needs to be within a section of a page (in fact in my scenario that's the case).

Note that the I've tried transitioning on the `width` property [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/qBrrEQq), but you can see the visible reflow of content inside the sidebar. Here's a .gif of it:

[image]

Ideally I'd like to do this without using JavaScript for the animation, but I'm open to it if there are no other good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this I would say is to give a % based width to your `pabel-content`.

Add these two properties to the class like this

```
.panel-content {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

This should remove the wrapping while animation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this will work with complex content in the sidebar (I've updated the question with that requirement).

Comment: It probably works with any content, you just need to set the Width of your inner container.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to - I tried it here: https://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/xxqqYLr

Comment: Updated my answer. It was because `width` alone was not enforcing enough.

Comment: Interesting and creative technique  - min-width alone seems to do the trick. However, `vw` units are relative to the viewport, whereas I actually need the 3 columns to be relative to an immediate parent container. An example is in my specific scenario where there's actually a left panel on the full page and the 3 column layout is within a right panel. Sorry I keep refining the requirements!

Comment: The idea here is that the container which you don't want to get disturbed by the animation needs to be of a fixed width. It works even with a fixed value like `min-width: 300px;`. try it out.

Comment: I know I've tried that, but am trying to achieve this without a fixed width. Maybe it's not possible. But probably there is *some* creative workaround, whether that's using javascript and animation, animationEnd callbacks, opacity, whatever...

Comment: Nah, not possible. When your inner container's width changes, all of it's children get automatically affected. The only other way to handle this, is to give specific widths to each and every child. Which is much worse than handling the parent. I don't think there will ever exist a solution without some width parameter being fixed. Because that's what causes the resizing. You can refer to popular website that have the same feature, facebook, google. This is how it is usually done.

Comment: Hi @jbyrd. Did you manage to find anything else ?

Comment: No I wasn't able to - I'm thinking JavaScript might be necessary here in order to avoid a hard-coded fixed width. For example, before collapsing, check the actual width of the `.panel-content` container, then set the CSS width to that. (...trying to think how to get the width you want it to be when expanding it again) - but I would like to also look for an example on a popular site like google or facebook, as you mentioned.

Comment: interesting, this is kinda how `ReactTransitionGroup`s work. Try going through it's documentation once. But I feel that would be overly complicating the situtation. You could always also store your width in a variable and use it again when expanding it. But you would have to maintain a lot of states while the transitioning happens